# "'doskey' is not recognized" when using Cmder

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmder

I'm trying to use Cmder (version 1.2) for common tasks on my Windows 7, but I'm having some issues `doskey`: when I start the Cmder displays this error message:

`'doskey' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Executing the `doskey` command directly from Windows' CLI seems perfectly OK.

How can I fix this?

Comment: cmder 1.2 is obsolete version. Update it first.

Comment: According to the [Github repository](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder), 1.2 _is_ the latest version.

Comment: There is at least [1.2.9](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/releases)

Comment: Clearing your PATH from outdated stuff can help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this error (and many others I was having with Cmder).

Actually, **I just added `C:\Windows\System32\` to the PATH.**

1. To do so, rigth-click on the `Computer` icon (on the Desktop or Start Menu) and choose `Properties`;
2. On the top left, click on `Advanced system settings`;
3. A small window pops up. Click on `Environment Variables...` at the bottom;
4. On the Panel `User variables for [your name here]` choose the line starting with `PATH` (generally, the second);
5. Double click on the value (right part) of aforementioned line or click on `edit` underneath the panel **and be careful NOT to delete its content**;
6. At the very end of the `value` add a ";" if there is none, then add `C:\Windows\System32;` (**mind the ; and the end**);
7. Click `Ok` twice to validate the update.

**P.S.**: You have to restart (close and reopen) your Cmder for these changes to take effect.

That was it!

Comment: I hope these steps are clear!

Answer (score 1):

Correct path for doskey.exe should be C:\Windows\System32

**Check also if your path does not exceed 2047 characters. When PATH variable is to long paths might not working.**

Comment: the path depends from the Win version, but there is a nice shortcut:
`%SystemRoot%\system32`

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you don't have the elevated privileges you can also achieve this using the cmder "Settings" under "Environment".

Steps:

1. Press Win+Alt+P to open settings.
2. On the left side of the settings window, under "Startup", select "Environment".
3. Add this line to the text box

   `set PATH=C:\Windows\System32\"`
4. You're all set!