# "Python" working but "Py" is not

Tags: command-line, python, environment-variables

I'm on Windows 10 and have Python 3.9.0 installed. The evinronment variables I have for Python are `C:\Users\Zimplfy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\` and `C:\Users\Zimplfy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\scripts\` in PATH. For some reason whenever I type `py` inside Command Prompt I get:

> 'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

But when I type in `python` I get:

> Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Anyone have an answer to why this could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your environment PATH variable that contains the directory for Python.  Please **edit** your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: `py` is a separate program and must be selected during the Python installation process (assuming you are using vanilla Python from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/)). If you are using another distribution of Python (e.g. Anaconda), this program may or may not be included.

Answer (score 2):

Run in the command line:

`doskey py = python`

This creates an alias for the `python` command and then you can use `py` to start the python interpreter.

If you get an error regarding `doskey` not being recognized as an internal or external command, add `C:\Windows\System32;` to the **PATH** and run the command again. You can follow the more detailed instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/988311/doskey-is-not-recognized-when-using-cmder) to modify the **PATH**.

Comment: this is working. thanx a lot for sharing this accurate answer. this answer must be checked as problem answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by checking

```
> where py
```

for example on my machine the output is

C:\Windows\py.exe

so if the py is missing and you have standard python installation then you need need to make sure that C:\WINDOWS is in the path by setting env path
WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS

verify

```
echo %WINDIR%
```

if there is still no py.exe then reinstall python

Answer (score 0):

The main answer is "[Yomie](https://superuser.com/a/1750199/1462946)" answer at top. the main problem is `doskey` output is not permanent and it will be undefined again if you close your command line. I combined [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1750199/1462946) with [this](https://superuser.com/a/1294155/1462946) for better experience.

- First add `C:\Windows\System32` to system paths for working doskey. Then create a doskey file and add it `py=python $*` and save it for example as example: `C:\bat\macros.doskey`.
- Then in your Start Menu search `registry editor` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\`.
- Right click and add `Autorun`.
- Then right click on it and click on modify and write your doskey path example `C:\bat\macros.doskey`.
- Then start your command line again and you will see that `py` is working again and is a permanent command.